# pip install urllib2 #failed

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to install urllib2 in cmd console to import it from python 3.5.
I am getting this error:

```
pip install urllib2
```

> Failed building wheel for urllib2
>
> Command "c:\anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7meqhp18\urllib2\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-it4nmmne-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NA401134\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7meqhp18\urllib2\

Comment: what version of `pip` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) is a built-in package in Python 2. You don't need to `pip install` it. Did you mean [urllib3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3)?

Comment: I am using python 3.5 so it will be urllib3